# Asking Turtle to evaluate color of different breed of Turtle

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm building interactions for a prey-predator model.

I have a prey that changes color based on the state that it is currently in. The state that I'm working on is "hiding", in which the prey is yellow. I have a predator working to evaluate if it can chase a prey, I'm attempting to do this by evaluating the color of the prey but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
to chase
  let target min-one-of prey [distance myself]
  output-print target
  ifelse target != yellow 
  [

     output-print "chase"
  ]
  [
    output-print "ignore"
  ]
end
```

When I run the model the predator constantly prints "chase" - regardless of whether the prey is "hiding" or not.

Here is the hiding function.

```
to hiding
  set color yellow
  set energy (energy - 1)
  if (count predators = 0)
[
  output-print "safe"
]
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to access the color (or any other variable of an agent) you surround the variable name in brackets and use "of" thus

```
[color] of target
```

in context of your code it would look like this

```
 to chase
 let target nearest-of prey
 output-print target
 ifelse [color] of target != yellow 
 [

  output-print "chase"
 ]
 [
 output-print "ignore"
 ]
```

end

it takes some time to get used to as it is quite different than the object.variable form used by "C" style languages.